# .htaccess clean URL's while removing some variables?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I have this structure.

```
?id=83&download=jerhub&title=The Post - Title Here
```

Is it possible for me to make my URL structure something like this?

```
/83-the-post-title-here.html
```

Completely removing the download variable from the clean URL structure, while still being able to call it on page?

Comment: If the information is not in the URL, you can't magically conjure it up out of thin air. It's unclear where the `download` parameter would come from.

Comment: Yes, look into routing in php

Comment: @deceze What in the world are you talking about dude? He literally showed both examples...

Comment: @Placeholder Is the question how to make a rewrite rule that rewrites `/83-the-post-title-here.html` to `?id=83&download=jerhub&title=The Post - Title Here`? If so, is "`jerhub`" hardcoded then? If not, where's it coming from? If it's hardcoded, then what's the question exactly?

Comment: @deceze It seems that he wants to turn `?id=83&download=jerhub&title=The Post - Title Here` into `/83-the-post-title-here.html` which is more then possible.

Comment: @Placeholder That's not how rewriting works. You typically rewrite a "pretty" URL into a query-string URL. Meaning you start with the pretty URL in your HTTP request and rewrite it into the query string for your server to process. However you come up with the pretty URL in your HTML is up to you. But I don't see a way to take that pretty URL and turn it into that query string. The other way around has little to do with [tag:.htaccess].